# Using ImageMagick to remove all color except black in an image?

Tags: colors, imagemagick

The situation is : I have many images of documents from scanning. I want to keep the document's main content - which is printed in color black (a small range of colors around #000000). But, you know, the documents are always full of colors : stamp, background, decorations, logos...etc.

I just want to keep the TEXTS ONLY which were printed in the color black.

I've tried with [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org) and this command so far:

```
convert X.png -matte (+clone -fuzz 20% -transparent "#000000") -compose DstOut -composite X1.png
```

But the result was not as expected , the text was very damaged that I cannot read.
Someone suggested me to increase the fuzz to 70%:

```
convert X.png -matte (+clone -fuzz 70% -transparent "#000000") -compose DstOut -composite X1.png
```

Then the text appeared to be more readable, but the other colors kept remaining too.

Can you please show me a better solution for my situation? Every suggestion would be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 30, accepted):

To match **all colors except black** you can use `+opaque "#000000"`.

In order to include a little range around #000000 you can try different percentages with the `fuzz` operator:

```
convert input.png -fill white -fuzz 10% +opaque "#000000" result.png
```

*Tested with ImageMagick 6.6.0-1 on Windows*

Comment: Once you go above 55% fuzz it includes red but not some greys, colors like #D9D9D9 are ignored. Is there a way to only keep all pixels that to us look like black/light black. Or to specify a range of colors?

Answer (score 5):

I stumbled upon this question while looking for an answer to this question. I found a couple imagemagick forum posts that helped. Here is what I came up with:

```
convert input.gif -matte \( +clone -fuzz 1 -transparent black \) -compose DstOut -composite ~/Desktop/output.png
```

Forum post: [ImageMagick: Removing all but one color](http://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=9568&start=0)

Comment: Yes, thanks. But your solution is absolutely the same as what I posted above.

Answer (score 4):

You should try the [level](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/color_mods/) command:

```
convert test.png -level 25%,75% test_level.png
```