# Setting transparency to different colored backgrounds imageMagick

Tags: pdf, imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

I need to process some pdfs to transparent pngs the pdfs are text-only with colored backgrounds.

The pdfs have varied colored backgrounds, Some are lightgray, some are white etc. but they are consistent throughout the pdf.

Is there a way in imagemagick where I can identify the left topmost pixel color and pass the acquired color to the command `-transparent "identifiedColor"` while executing the imagemagick command?

Thanks !

Comment: Is your text black or is it coloured?

Comment: If your text is always black, then Andrea's [answer elsewhere](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15426968/using-imagemagick-to-remove-all-color-except-black-in-an-image/20976373#20976373) should work. If the color of the text varies, I was trying to see if you could use something like `-transparent -fx 'p{0,0}' -fuzz 1%` but I couldn't get that to work. Does anyone know a way to use `-fx` to accomplish this?

Comment: @Andrea, Yes the text is a mix-up of colors, some are black, some are colored.

Comment: Actually I had seen an imagemagick command which does exactly what I asked in my question, But I am just unable to find it again. and it wasn't that difficult for a person who knows imagemagick and cmd.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Solution 1: matte floodfill**

```
convert input.pdf -fill none -fuzz 10% -draw "matte 0,0 floodfill" output.png
```

*Probably you'll have to adjust fuzz percentage*

more details here:  http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/draw/#matte

**Solution 2: color replace**

I could not find a way to do it in a single command, but these two commands should work:

1. replace background color (taken from pixel[0,0]) with white:

   ```
   convert input.pdf -fill white -draw "color 0,0 replace" temp.png
   ```
2. make white pixels transparent:

   ```
   convert temp.png -transparent white output.png
   ```

more details here http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/draw/#color

*Tested with ImageMagick 6.6.0-1 on Windows*

Comment: I think the second solution will do. I played with the `fuzz` beforehand but it wont work in my case.

Comment: Solution 2 can be done in one command like this: `convert input.pdf -fill none -draw "color 0,0 replace" output.png`