# Imagick: change hue of color range so it becomes different color

Tags: imagick

I'm writing a small open-source game and up to this point I've made all the graphics myself (yeah, that's hardcore, but that was the point).

Now using Imagick in image representing hero **I'd like to replace the orange shirt which has few shades of orange with different color (so basically change its hue, but with appliance to only "orange" color)**. So the shirt becomes green (or any other color).

It's too much for me as I'm beginner with Imagick. How could I do it? Tried searching but no success.
Thanks for help to everyone willing to help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to solve it with this code:

```
convert input.png -fill "#00cccc" -fuzz 10%% -opaque rgb(255,127,38) output.png
```

Inspired by: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20976373/3107185