# Remove surrounding lines and background graphic noise from handwritten text

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, imagemagick

I am trying to remove rules and a background smiley face from multiple notebook pages before performing text detection and recognition on the handwritten text.

[image]

An [earlier thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33949831/whats-the-way-to-remove-all-lines-and-borders-in-imagekeep-texts-programmatic) offers helpful hints, but my problem is different in several respects.

1. The text to keep is written over the background items to be removed.
2. The items to be removed have distinct colors from that of the text, which may be the key to their removal.
3. The lines to be removed are not very straight, and the smiley face even less so.

I'm thinking of using OpenCV for this task, but I'm open to using ImageMagick or command-line GIMP so long as I can process the entire batch at once. Since I have never used any of these tools before, any advice would be welcome. Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using ImageMagick to remove all color except black in an image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15426968/using-imagemagick-to-remove-all-color-except-black-in-an-image)

Comment: You could try thresholding on blue hue from HSV so that blue becomes white and all other colors are black. What have you tried?

Comment: do you have uncompressed images? jpeg is not ideal for high resolution stuff based on colour as most of the compressing is done on the colour information

Comment: Assuming that the text is blue, you can use color thresholding to obtain a mask 
of the text outline then perform smoothing operations to isolate the characters. This way, you can concurrently remove the smiley face and the lines

Answer (score 2):

Here's a simple approach with the assumption that the text is blue

- Convert image to HSV format and color threshold with [`cv2.inRange()`](https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_colorspaces/py_colorspaces.html)
- Perform [morphological transformations](https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_morphological_ops/py_morphological_ops.html) to smooth image
- Isolate characters
- Recolor characters for OCR/Tesseract

---

We begin by converting the image to HSV format and create a mask to isolate the characters

```
image = cv2.imread('1.png')
result = image.copy()
image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
lower = np.array([21,0,0])
upper = np.array([179, 255, 209])
mask = cv2.inRange(image, lower, upper)
```

[image]

Now we perform morphological transformations to remove small noise

```
kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_ELLIPSE, (2,2))
close = cv2.morphologyEx(mask, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel, iterations=1)
```

[image]

We have the desired text outlines so we can isolate characters by masking with the original image

```
result[close==0] = (255,255,255)
```

[image]

Finally to prepare the image for OCR/Tesseract, we change the characters to black

```
retouch_mask = (result <= [250.,250.,250.]).all(axis=2)
result[retouch_mask] = [0,0,0]
```

[image]

Full code

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

image = cv2.imread('1.png')
result = image.copy()
image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
lower = np.array([21,0,0])
upper = np.array([179, 255, 209])
mask = cv2.inRange(image, lower, upper)

kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_ELLIPSE, (2,2))
close = cv2.morphologyEx(mask, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel, iterations=1)

result[close==0] = (255,255,255)

cv2.imshow('cleaned', result)

retouch_mask = (result <= [250.,250.,250.]).all(axis=2)
result[retouch_mask] = [0,0,0]

cv2.imshow('mask', mask)
cv2.imshow('close', close)
cv2.imshow('result', result)
cv2.waitKey()
```

Comment: Thank you, but I don't think filling the mask with black will work very well, because (1) the training data is [gray-scale](https://coding.tools/blog/casia-handwritten-chinese-character-recognition-using-convolutional-neural-network-and-similarity-ranking) and (2) the mask has a low fidelity to the original characters (e.g. it turns four horizon strokes in the bottom left-hand character into a solid triangle). There should be a way to use the mask to apply effects only to the characters so that they resemble the linked training examples, right?

Comment: I don't understand why filling the mask with black won't work. You can convert the image to grayscale with `cv2.cvtColor()` then use the training data. The characters may look merged since the smoothing filter is large, you can adjust this filter to "unmerge" but you will have more noise